# Visual studio project and item template auto add something to config file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, app-config, itemtemplate

I'm trying to create templates for projects and items in visual studio.
And I wonder.
Can we do something like add some config in app.config when adding some item.
Or some cool context menu allow us to add property, setter injection and auto config in spring.net config file (like how we add view from controller in asp.net mvc2 controller template).

And if we can, how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find the answer myself...
wizard extensions and configuration api will do the trick